# Dropdown list selecteditem or selectedindex not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList and a function that gets what the value is selected but the SelectedIndex and the SelectedValue always return the first item.

The DropDown code is

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lstApps" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDataSource" 
                        DataTextField="some_val" DataValueField="some_id"
                        TabIndex="5" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and the code (in a button click even of a button somewhere on the page)

```
int x = lstApps.SelectedIndex;
```

always returns 0 despite of what I might have selected. Is it due to auto postback being disabled or some other reason?

Comment: Please check if in page_load you are binding within `! (IsPostback)` clause ?

Comment: just saw that. facepalm.

Comment: I guess then that must have fixed your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess! You need to use `IsPostBack` block in `Page_Load` event.

```
public void Page_Load()
{
  if(!IsPostBack) 
  {
     //put databinding code here.
  }
}
```